# Vim incremental search during substitution

Tags: regex, vim

I am terrible at writing vim regular expressions. Whenever I write one to do a substition, it never works the first time because I inevitably end up writing something Perl instead of vim. I fare a lot better when doing a simple search because I have `incsearch` turned on and I can see in real-time whether my pattern matches.

Is there a way I can have the s command act like / (performing an incremental search) while I am attempting to write a proper pattern?

Comment: Vim 8.1 has added support for incsearch on :s, :g, and :v via patch 8.1.0271

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think there is not a way to do it. By the way, I use a little trick to speed up my substitutions. If you do something like:

```
:%s//bar
```

on the command line Vim will use your latest search. So, it's not exactly what you need but still a way to increase a bit your speed doing substitutions.

Comment: This is good tip. You can just type your search out first, then run that shortcut

Comment: Wow, that tip will probably save me many hours over the course of my career. Thanks!

Comment: I knew I could search again with /, but it never occured to me that it would carry over to substitute as well!

Answer (score 3):

You could try this little trick to compose your search pattern using incsearch and then copy pattern into command line substitution:

1. Compose pattern using normal mode /...
   You can see your patterns are matching.
   The last pattern will be stored in the @/ register.
2. Go to command line mode and enter this partial line:  `:%s/`
3. Now press these keys: `<c-r>=@/`
   This will copy last search pattern into the
   substitute command you're writing.  ( `<c-r>` is pressing control-r key, not typing in the characters.)